# Why is PHP's $_ENV (for Environment Variables) unavailable on Azure Websites?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

The `$_ENV` dictionary is unavailable on PHP Microsoft Azure Websites. You must use `getenv` instead.

I found this page: http://aarondancer.com/2015/08/16/accessing-environment-variables-on-an-azure-web-app-in-php/

However I want to know why this is the case. Is there a php.ini setting to control this?

This does break some applications of mine that depend on `$_ENV` existing. I can shim it by creating it myself, but how can I enumerate environment variables so I can fully populate it?

Comment: It's one of PHP's more confusing aspects. Specifically (TL;DR on the dupe) `The getenv function worked because it apparently searches both $_ENV and $_SERVER`. So it's deceptive in what it's setting and where.